# Merge Tool only includes input feature class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, merge

My colleague and I split some work up between us, and I'd like to merge the two sets of feature classes back into one.

Here's the code I'm using to compare the fc's and use them in the merge tool:

```
import arcpy
import os

# Comparing my fc with colleague's fc
def compare(x, y):
    if x.rstrip('_colleague') == y.rstrip('_original'):
        return(True)

# Merging compared fc's
for i in fcList:
    for j in fcList:
        if compare(i, j):
            outputName = i.rstrip('_colleague') + 'MergeOutput'
#             print(outputName)
            arcpy.management.Merge(inputs = f"'C:\Park Maintenance.gdb\{i}';'C:\Park Maintenance.gdb\{j}'",
                                   output = f'C:\Park Maintenance.gdb\{outputName}')
```

For some reason the only fc's that are returned are my own, and don't include my colleague's. As you can see from the code, my colleague's fc's are the first fc's passed to the merge tool - so I'm not sure why my fc's are accepted as input objects and not my colleague's.

Does anyone have any ideas where my code is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax - multiple inputs should be formatted as a list of files, rather than a semicolon separated string. Something like `inputs=[f"'C:\Park Maintenance.gdb\{i}'", f"'C:\Park Maintenance.gdb\{j}'"]`

For more details see [Esri Merge documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this tomorrow when I get in. I was confused because the formatting I gave is what I retrieved by grabbing esri's code from the geoprocessing history window!

Comment: For future reference every tool you can use in ArcGIS Pro has the arcpy syntax spelled out (and some minor code examples given) as part of the standard documentation page online. I would probably start there instead of just looking at the geoprocessing history window.

Comment: So I placed the two inputs as f strings in a list as opposed to the original code, and I changed the output location to a new empty file gdb in the C:\ drive. However, the merged output is still only including one set of the inputs. I'm not sure what's happening here?

Comment: Weird. Ok, then this is where I'd start throwing in print statements to check your strings with i/j/outputName are what you'd expect, that your feature class list has all the expected files, and maybe do some manual testing with a couple of the files to make sure they contain the data you expect and merge as desired. Good luck!

Comment: ['C:\\Park Maintenance.gdb\\AccessPerimeterClearance_new', 'C:\\Park Maintenance.gdb\\AccessPerimeterClearance_original'] --- Is my output when I print my f strings in the loop, I can't think what would cause and issue if one is getting through and not the other - perhaps a bug? I hesitate to say bug because in 99% of cases its a user error.